# Different login hosts for each login on cluster

Tags: linux, ssh, login, hostname

I have just obtained an account on a new cluster. It is running RHEL 6.
I logged simultaneously from a couple of different terminal windows via SSH.
What I noticed was that each login resulted in a different hostname being given.
For example, I was logged in 3 times as:

```
me@hostlog1
me@hostlog3
me@hostlog4
```

For example, typing `hostname` on the first terminal would give me:  `hostlog1`
and on the last terminal typing `hostname` gave:  `hostlog4`

This isn't something I've seen before, and it caused me a little bit of a problem.  While logged in on hostlog1, for example, I started a tmux session and left it open.
When I logged in later, I was then logged into hostlog3, and I couldn't see or re-attach to that tmux session.  I had to be logged in on hostlog1 to see the tmux session.

I was wondering a few things.

1. What is this called?
2. Why is it done?  (security, convenience, etc)
3. How do I manage this, and/or can I restrict myself to always being logged in on the same host?

Regards, Madeleine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two main goals of are clustering are:

1) High Availability - usually achieved through Active/Passive

This is where you have x+1(or more) systems, and, if anyone fails - an extra picks up the slack.

2) High Performance/Scalability - usually achieved through Active/Active

This is usually much more awkward to setup, but, it is where you have multiple systems online at once at the same time and you have some sort of higher mechanism that points you to the correct node.

So....

1. I think this must be an active/active cluster
2. There is probably some higher device (load balancer, or even just something simple like Round Robin DNS) that targets you to a different node. This gives the system the highest level of throughput as if there are 4 nodes and each request goes to a different host, you can have 4x the amount of sessions.
3. Most devices that have this sort of setup have both a cluster/resource shared ip/address which you are most likely connecting to in addition to their local ip which is usually used for administration.... This is what you need to log on to.